# iphone scrollview keyboard hides text input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, scrollview

I have a long data entry screen about 1200 high.  I can scroll OK between the fields for data entry using the finger swiping.

I think I should be able to go to the next field when I press enter on the keyboard or some key?  If so how do you do that?

Also unless I position the text enter at the top of the screen, when the keyboard pops up if covers the text box.

I am guessing this problem along with the one above might all be to do with making sure the text boxes move to the top of the screen for input?

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to add buttons to advance through your various controls, I believe you would have to customize the keyboard view with your own buttons and then have them invoke the "becomeFirstResponder" selector on each control as appropriate.
2. To prevent the keyboard from covering the scroll view you'll want to respond to the notification that the keyboard has been presented and readjust the size of your scroll view to only occupy the area above the keyboard. [Apple's UICatalog sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) has examples for how to do this.